# get metadata from wordpress custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy that I am using on a custom post type. I have added a custom field to my taxonomy through Advance Custom Fields.

I need to call the meta data that is selected on my taxonomy.php page. I can call the id of the custom taxonomy with this code...

```
$term = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title('slug',false) );
echo $term
```

This returns the taxonomy id correctly, so now I just need to query the metadata of this specific id to find the value of field 'list_template'

help is appreciated

Comment: I've tried this...but it's breaking    $term = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title('',false) );
 $template = get_tax_meta( $term, 'list_template' );

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm with same issue here

Comment: just added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_post_meta function in wordpress to achieve this, that's a link[get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to it in the wordpress codex.

Comment: get_post_meta doesn't seem to be working for taxonomy meta. unless there is a way for me to pass the taxonomy id in the get_post_meta function

Answer (score 0):

I did. Here is the code I used.

```
$templateCategory = "patient_category_$catIdChild";
$template = get_field('list_template', $templateCategory );
```

patient_category is my custom taxonomy slug. So just use your slug in it's place.

$catIdChild is the custom taxonomy ID. So once you have your tax ID, you can plug that variable in to get query that specific taxonomy.

list_template is the slug of my custom field on my taxonomy page, so obviously replace it with your custom field slug.

Let me know if you need some help with it.